# File execution order

Tags: themes

I have a WordPress site which I manage(I am not a developer) I ran a [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.texasarrestwarrants.org%2F&tab=mobile) test. I got some issues like caching problems and so on so I used several plugins to take care of them. however I'm now stuck with Optimize CSS Delivery problems.

So I thought to try and fix it by myself and move the problematic URLs to the end of the page, however I cant figure out where these URLS are coming from. or which page is requesting for them.

```
<!-- head -->
<head>

<!-- meta -->
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<?php if( mfn_opts_get('responsive') ) echo '<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">'; ?>

<title><?php
global $post;
if( mfn_opts_get('mfn-seo') && is_object($post) && get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 
'mfn-meta-seo-title', true ) ){
echo stripslashes( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-meta-seo-title', true ) );
} else {
global $page, $paged;
wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
bloginfo( 'name' );
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'limuso' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
}
?></title>

<?php if( is_single() ): ?>
<script>var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script>stLight.options({publisher: "ur-6568e777-919c-a5dd-ac31-98a6fa2e6b2d"}); </script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php do_action('wp_seo'); ?>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php mfn_opts_show('favicon-img',THEME_URI .'/images/favicon.ico'); ?>" type="image/x-icon" /> 

<!-- wp_head() -->
<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
```

appreciate any help with this

Comment: which URLs, can you show the <head> part? just edit your question and add a screenshot

Comment: Hi. updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this: `<script src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>` Try to add this to the body or footer of your site and then remove the link to w.sharethis.com. Because this not a local js it will not be cached and this will show as a js / css error in pagespeed.  You could save this as a local file and then change the link from sharethis.com to your local file or you can use a plugin like [cache external scripts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cache-external-scripts/)

hope this helps

Comment: plugin messed up my site functionality. will try the first solution.